# asp GridView is not getting binded

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Issue with my code is that I'm trying to update the data table(removing few rows) and then trying to assign it to grid view data-source. data table is getting updated and In Gridview.DataSource=dt; (DataSource is showing up the perfect data) but Gridview is not getting updated.

Do I need to add something here??

```
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                BindData();

                try
                {
                    GridViewTree1.DataBind();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    throw;
                }

            }

            GridViewTree1.Visible = true;
            GridViewHistory.Visible = false;
            dt = Session["dt"] as DataTable;

            DeleteParentRowsWithNoChilds(dt);
            dt.AcceptChanges();
            GridViewTree1.EditIndex = -1;
            GridViewTree1.DataSource = dt;
            GridViewTree1.DataBind();

        }


        private void DeleteParentRowsWithNoChilds(DataTable dt)
        {
            DataRow[] FolderRows;
            FolderRows = dt.Select("IsFolder='true'");
            foreach (DataRow row in FolderRows)
            {
                int RowId = int.Parse(row["Id"].ToString());
                int nextRowid = RowId + 1;
                DataRow[] nextrow = dt.Select("Id='" + nextRowid + "'");
                if (nextrow.Count() > 0 && !nextrow[0].ToString().Contains('\\'))
                {
                    dt.Rows.Remove(row);

                }
                //If it is a last row
                else
                {
                    dt.Rows.Remove(row);
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: add  GridViewTree1.DataSource = null; code before   GridViewTree1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: how are you assigning value to Session["dt"] ?

Comment: @MuradGaribzada..I tried.But still the dvtree in GridViewTree1 is not getting reflected with updated values

Comment: @Usman..My datatable is perfect.It got updated.My issue is that the gridViewTree1 is not getting assigned with datatable values.

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing is deleting the `rows` but not updating the `session dt` thats why it is always getting the previous values in `datatable` so you should update the `session` after deleting the `rows` like

```
private void DeleteParentRowsWithNoChilds(DataTable dt)
        {
            DataRow[] FolderRows;
            FolderRows = dt.Select("IsFolder='true'");
            foreach (DataRow row in FolderRows)
            {
                int RowId = int.Parse(row["Id"].ToString());
                int nextRowid = RowId + 1;
                DataRow[] nextrow = dt.Select("Id='" + nextRowid + "'");
                if (nextrow.Count() > 0 && !nextrow[0].ToString().Contains('\\'))
                {
                    dt.Rows.Remove(row);

                }
                //If it is a last row
                else
                {
                    dt.Rows.Remove(row);
                }

            }
                Session["dt"] = dt;

       }
```